# Spark - move files after processing them

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, delta-lake

I read json files into dataframe:
`df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(f"/mnt/bronze/{something}*")`

Then I do some processing and after that I write it to delta table:
`rows.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(f"/mnt/silver/{something}")`

I want to move json files after processing so I don't reprocess them again in the future. But I don't know how to move them.

I tried using dbutils inside rdd.foreach() but it's not possible. I also tried shutil.move() inside rdd.foreach() but then my files are not found because I use blob storage.

Comment: Instead of moving files once processed, have you considered writing the files into the definitive destination?

Comment: Can you give small example?

Comment: Just .save(f"/mnt/silver/{something definitive that is not necessary to move}")

Comment: Where do you need to move your files? An Azure Blob storage, Amazon S3, etc?

Comment: I do saving already. My problem is that I run this notebook 1 time per day. Source container will have new files everyday, and I don't want to process files that I already processed yesterday. So I thought maybe moving files will solve this issue. For example, moving to folder "/mnt/bronze/archive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide some solutions.

I suppose /mnt/bronze/{something} is your stagging area to land files and you want to prevent reading files from previous landings.

You have some options at the end of your current notebook:

1. remove the raw files if they are no longer needed:

```
dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/bronze/{something}*", True)
```

`dbutils.fs.rm` is the function to remove files, `"/mnt/bronze/{something}*"` is the path and pattern of the files you want to remove, and True as the second argument indicates that the deletion is recursive (it's optional if you're sure you're only deleting files).

2. If you may need the files in the future, just move them to a temporal directory where they can be safely deleted in the future

```
dbutils.fs.mv("/mnt/bronze/{something}*", "/mnt/tmp/")
```

PD: If you go with 2) I recommend to add some rules based on timestamps in the paths of tmp/ dir to ensure you maintain it organised and clean. As for example `f"mnt/tmp/{today()}"`

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what would happen if after writing to delta table, the file movement fail, I would reprocess old files and delta table will contain duplicates. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Since you seem to be running just once per day - see if you can write the JSON files into dated folder, then consume them using date.For eg. consider the files are in `/mnt/bronze/2024-02-01` - your script would calculate the date and read it from that path. So in case the file movement/deletion fails, the subsequent files would fall on the `2024-02-02` folder, hence would not get duplicated.Of course, you need to contend with the additional logic and also consider what happens if the job reading data fails and you need to re-run for 2024-02-01 on 02-Feb. Basically ability to handle adhoc runs

Comment: That what I said in the response :)

Comment: Agreed - only intended to explain further in case of the old files and other things to consider..